# Can't change the data inside the void function

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add to the int variable named counter each time it goes through a for function but it doesn't seems to be adding up as it isn't in the scope.

```
int test(String carNumber) {
    int counter = 0;

    Firestore.instance
        .collection('Notes')
        .document('LoanedEquipments')
        .collection(carNumber)
        .getDocuments()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      snapshot.documents.forEach((f) {
        print(f.data['Items']);
        counter++;
      });
    });
    return counter;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try the code below,

```
Future<int> test(String carNumber) async {
    int counter = 0;

    QuerySnapshot snapShot=await Firestore.instance
        .collection('Notes')
        .document('LoanedEquipments')
        .collection(carNumber)
        .getDocuments();

    if(snapShot!=null){
      snapShot.documents.forEach((f) {
        print(f.data['Items']);
        counter++;
      });
    }

    return counter;
  }
```

You are not getting your counter value appropriate as you are updating counter value inside then method which will be called after your Querysnapshot data from firebase.

Your Querysnapshot will take some time to query data from the firebase. So, before your Querysnapshot data is fetched your method return your initial counter value.

So, use await method to wait till the Querysnapshot fetches data from the firebase and calculate the counter value and then return the counter value.